# Unable to save data using jquery which is lengthy

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a textareafor

```
<div class="inner-addon left-addon">
     Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.DataFixes, new { @class = "resizedTextbox", id = "txtDataFixes", placeholder = "Data Fixes" , style = "width : 70px,height : 70px;" })
</div>
```

I have used jquery to save the data using the button click. When i click on the save button then iam able to save the data in the textbox for when the data entered is small, But when i try to  save a lengthy data, it doesnot get saved. The below is my jquery code. I think it has something to do with the var object.

```
$('#btnUpdateDataSet').click(function() {
    var note = $("#txtNote").val();
    var fileContentName = $("#txtFileContentName").val();
    var fileContentId = $("#fileContentId").val();
    var dataFixes = $("#txtDataFixes").val();

    var oldWorkitemId = $('#drpOldWorkitemId option:selected').val();

    if (fileContentName.length == 0) {
        var fileContentId = null;
    } else {
        var fileContentId = $("#fileContentId").val();
    }
    updateDataSet(workItemID, dataSetDateStamp, cycle, reference, feed, source, target, lineStart, extension, note, fileContentId, dataFixes, oldWorkitemId);
});
```

The below is my controller

```
public ActionResult EditDataSet(  string dataFixes)
{
    EditDataSetVM editDataSetVM = new EditDataSetVM();

    editDataSetVM.DataFixes = dataFixes;
    return PartialView("EditDataSetView", editDataSetVM);
}
```

My Ajax call

```
function updateDataSet(workItemID, dataSetDateStamp, cycle, reference, feed, source, target, lineStart, extension, note, fileContentId, dataFixes,oldWorkitemId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DataSet/UpDateDataSetDetails",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "workItemId": workItemID, "dataSetDateStamp":

        dataSetDateStamp, "cycle": cycle, "reference": reference, "feed": feed, "source": source, "target": target, "lineStart": lineStart, "extension":

        extension, "note": note, "fileContentId": fileContentId, "dataFixes": 

        dataFixes, "oldWorkitemId": oldWorkitemId },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "Update Succeeded") {
                $("#btnViewDataSet").click();
            }
            else {
                $("div.toshow").show();
                $('#lblUpdateDataSetResult').html('Following error(s) occured:<br\>' + data);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Update WorkItem metadata failed.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your text says `textboxfor` but your code says `TextAreaFor`

Comment: `"I Guess it has something to do with the Var Object in jquery."` - What on Earth does that even mean?  Where is your JavaScript code?  How specifically is this failing?  Be specific, you have to describe the problem for anybody to help.

Comment: you said large data is not able to store that means small string can be saved .. Right ...?

Comment: @rush.2707 - yes

Comment: just a try ... what if you try it with javascript. I really wonder how long value will be it that you can not get with JQuery. I can understand if it is not getting controller side ... and if that also dont work than try for urlencode thing.

Comment: and one suggestion ... if you have created model and also using it than why to not use it to pass the data ? Make a submit button and use html.beginform/ajax.beginform.

Comment: could you help me how to do it. Iam new to all this.

Comment: what is happening inside your `updateDataSet` method ? is it a Ajax call or form submit ??

Comment: Its an ajax call

Comment: @Catwoman: So your long string is being truncated?  Is it always to a specific length?  When you debug this, where specifically is the value being truncated?

Comment: @David - yes my long string is being truncated

Comment: @Catwoman there is a limit on the amount of data that you can post... So I would say you have to post this huge data in terms of blobs..

Comment: @Catwoman: *Specifically where* is it being truncated?  In the click handler, what is the value of `dataFixes`?  Is the entire value included when you send it to the server?  Where is the server-side code you're calling?  You need to debug this.

Comment: No the entire value is not included.

Comment: @Catwoman: Sorry, but nobody here can help based on cryptic half-answers to our requests for clarification.  If you can be specific and provide information about the problem, we might be able to identify what's going wrong.  But nobody here can debug your code on your computer for you.

Comment: @Catwoman Try paginating your data, eg how a restfull service works, usually only found on the return data and not the post/payload, but it is not a limitation if you design it right. Alternatively use a socket to stream the data across